# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException Error while running spring application

Tags: java, spring

I have seen other related questions but was not satisfied with the solution.

I am new to spring and trying an example from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm

I have made my own changes to the above tutorial as per my requirement, like used city,country
entity instead of Student.

My Beans.XMl looks like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

<!-- Initialization for data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" 
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
  <property name="username" value="root"/>
  <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<!-- Definition for countryJDBCTemplate bean -->
<bean id="countryJDBCTemplate" 
  class="nz.org.tcf.CountryJDBCTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
</bean>

</beans>
```

and CountryJDBCTemplate.java looks like the below :

```
package nz.org.tcf;

import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import nz.org.tcf.v0_0_1.bif.dao.CountryDAO;
import nz.org.tcf.v0_0_1.bif.pojo.Country;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class CountryJDBCTemplate implements CountryDAO {
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
  this.dataSource = dataSource;
  this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);}

public void create(Integer population,String district,String countrycode,String name,      Integer id) {
String SQL = "insert into Student (population,district,countrycode,name,id) values   (?,?,?,?,?)";

jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, population,district,countrycode,name,id);
System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Countrycode = " + countrycode);
return;}

public Country getCountry(Integer id) {
String SQL = "select * from Student where id = ?";
Country country = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, 
                    new Object[]{id}, new CountryMapper());
return country;}

public List<Country> listCountries() {
String SQL = "select * from city";
List <Country> countries = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, 
                            new CountryMapper());
return countries;}

public void delete(Integer id){
String SQL = "delete from city where id = ?";
jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id );
return;}

public void update(Integer id, Integer population){
String SQL = "update city set population = ? where id = ?";
jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, population, id);
System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id );
 return;
}}
```

I get the following error when I run my main class

> Dec 11, 2013 1:06:02 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c7865b:
>   startup date [Wed Dec 11 13:06:02 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
>   Dec 11, 2013 1:06:02 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [Beans.xml] Dec 11, 2013 1:06:03 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   preInstantiateSingletons INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1fcb00e:
>   defining beans [dataSource,countryJDBCTemplate]; root of factory
>   hierarchy Dec 11, 2013 1:06:03 PM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
>   setDriverClassName INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'CountryJDBCTemplate' is defined   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
>     at nz.org.tcf.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:20)

---

MainApp.java is as follows:

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("In Main...");
  ApplicationContext context = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");     
  CountryJDBCTemplate CountryJDBCTemplate = 
  (CountryJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("CountryJDBCTemplate");

     System.out.println("------Listing Multiple Records--------" );
  List<Country> Countrys = CountryJDBCTemplate.listCountries();
  for (Country record : Countrys) {
     System.out.print("ID : " + record.getId() );
     System.out.print(", Name : " + record.getName() );

  }

  System.out.println("----Updating Record with ID = 2 -----" );
  CountryJDBCTemplate.update(2, 20);

  System.out.println("----Listing Record with ID = 2 -----" );
  Country Country = CountryJDBCTemplate.getCountry(2);
  System.out.print("ID : " + Country.getId() );
  System.out.print(", Name : " + Country.getName() );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bean is named `countryJDBCTemplate`:

```
<bean id="countryJDBCTemplate" ...>
```

But you are trying to access a bean named `CountryJDBCTemplate` (note the upper case `C`):

```
CountryJDBCTemplate CountryJDBCTemplate = (CountryJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("CountryJDBCTemplate");
```

Try retrieving the bean with using a lower case `c`:

```
CountryJDBCTemplate CountryJDBCTemplate = (CountryJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("countryJDBCTemplate");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Spring context, you're naming the bean `countryJDBCTemplate` with a lowercase C, but you're trying to retrieve a bean named `CountryJDBCTemplate` with an uppercase C.

(It really is better if at all possible to inject your Spring beans instead of looking them up manually. Spring Boot is a new project that makes this much easier.)